# How to prevent parent directory listing inside root folder when queried in the URL with APACHE server

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

In the .htaccess file when we type

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

If there is a directory that exists inside the root folder for example say errors. It will be shown if someone enters the URL. What can we do to prevent the opening of the parent directory structure directory in such a case? How to prevent exposing parent directory structure to the user in case of all the folders that exist in the root directory and queried inside the URL

like url= localhost/errors

Any command for that. I am using apache 2.4.46

Answer (score 1):

To prevent directory listing you can use `Options` directive

```
  Options -Indexes
```

This will show a 403 `forbidden error` if you try to access a directory on your server.

Comment: What is the use of Options MultiViews and FollowSymLinks??

Comment: @King619 `Options +Multiviews` enables mod-negotiations on apache server. With this line you can access your files without using their extensions at the end of URL. forexample if `Options +Multiviews` is set in htaccess then to access your `/file.html` you can just type short link `/file` . `FollowSymlinks` enable symlinks on the server. https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_negotiation.html

Comment: Can you also explain about Options symlinks...like you did for Options multiviews